# replace a substring using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a sample input file:

```
 $ cat test.txt 

 xz:xx.d.r1.latest
```

Now I want to replace a part with new value. For ex: I wanted to replace `r1` with `r2` in the above text so the new o/p would be

```
 xz:xx.d.r2.latest
```

I wanted to do this using variables. For example, consider the value to be replaced stored in variable `old` and the value to be replaced with in variable `new`:

```
 $ old=r1
 $ new=r2
```

Now for replacing, I tried

```
sed -i 's/'"${old}"'/'"${new}"'/g' test.txt
sed -i "s/$old}/${new}/g" test.txt
sed -i 's/'"$old"'/'"$new"'/g' test.txt
sed -i "s/${old}/${new}/g" test.txt
```

But none of them worked the value is not being replaced. So can anyone help me or tell whether the syntax is correct or what I am missing.

Comment: All of these commands except `sed -i "s/$old}/${new}/g" test.txt` work for me. Can you describe your problem in more details?

Comment: the values are not being replaced which I wanted. I think the command I used is not working

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk And that one didn't work cos you like he, were missing a {

Comment: The second and third commands are missing a { between the $ and o of ${old}

Comment: all four work for me(one must correct the second and third) https://pastebin.com/raw/dgr7dtmA

Comment: @barlop when I use the third command after correction i get the following error sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @DENDULURICHAITANYA things will be much clearer for you in troubleshooting things if you echo the sed expression e.g.  `echo 's/'"${old}"'/'"${new}"'/g'`   And why do you even need all of them to work.. they all do the same thing.    I think echoing the thing is definitely the solution to solving your problems, so long as you understand and know that ultimately a sed replace expression would look like 's/r1/r2/g'   when echoed, so, pretty simple, you'd just adapt the expression accordingly so that it echoes that.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using [BSD's `sed`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/sed/) (e.g. on macOS), `-i` option is a non-standard FreeBSD extension and it requires an argument. So to make sure you're using the right cross-compatible syntax, you should change it to:

```
sed -i'.bak' ... # rest of the command
```

Other than that, your commands are fine. E.g.

```
sed -i'.bak' 's/'"${old}"'/'"${new}"'/g' test.txt
```

Tested in Bash shell on WSL (Ubuntu on Windows).